# Hls streaming in ionic 3 using html video player

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, http-live-streaming, videojs-transcript

Is there any possible way to use videojs library in ionic 3 ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to play videos on Ionic 3 app or you must need to use above library?

Comment: I need to play in ionic app . Do you have any idea ? Because when i try to install videojs through npm , i got this error  "Cannot find module "safe-json-parse/tuple". And when i try with the cdn link then i got this error "
Specified “type” attribute of “application/x-mpegURL” is not supported. Load of media resource https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8 failed.
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: application/x-mpegURL"

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use [**native video Player plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/) for that.

> A Cordova plugin that simply allows you to immediately play a video in
>   fullscreen mode.

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git 
npm install --save @ionic-native/video-player
```

**OR** You can use `HTML 5 video tag`:

[**Ionic and HTML5 video tag**](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-and-html5-video-tag/78030/2)

Comment: Thank you but i neeed to show that player in ionic view , which is not possible in the case of native plugin.

Comment: `videojs` uses HTML 5 player. So can't you use it without that library?  See this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-and-html5-video-tag/78030/2